# How to read current time in python without a package?

Tags: python

I'm in an environment that doesn't allow importing `time` or `datetime`, is there an alternative for reading the system's time?

Comment: What "environment" wouldn't allow that? Those are ***built-in*** modules...

Comment: A call to the shell would work, but this requires `os` or `sys` imports.  Both builtin, same as `datetime` and `time`.

Comment: there are not any alternatives... `datetime` and `time` module is built-in so there should not be any error

Answer (score 2):

If you **really** need to do so and you are under linux system, it is possible to do a trick with `date` command, like

```
date > time.txt | python -c "print(open('time.txt', 'r').read().strip())" && rm time.txt
```

outputs

```
Tue Dec  1 12:05:05 MSK 2020
```

But as many people already stated, importing `time` or `datetime` should not be a problem, because they are built-in's

Comment: @S3DEV thx, nice suggestion, added to the post

Answer (score 1):

On a Linux system you can look at the RTC:

```
print(open('/sys/class/rtc/rtc0/time').read())
```

Output:

```
10:10:07
```